# IF statement is giving the wrong results in excel

Tags: excel

[image: Edited workings]

I am trying to get the 'delivery today?' column to reflect either Y or N. When column M is 0, I want it to reflect N and when column M is not O to reflect Y.

I have tried =IF(L15=0;"N";"Y"), this results in a circular reference or give an opposing result. I am not sure what else to try.

Thank you.

Comment: IF you want to test column M, then you should probably test cell `M15`, not `L15`: `=IF(M15=0;"N";"Y"),`

Comment: Do your data starts from row 15? From screenshot it seems your data starts from row 3.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to test column L. Column M is empty. It was a typo originally.

Comment: The data starts from row 15. I have reuploaded a new picture.

Comment: If that is giving you a circular reference, the value in L15 depends on the value in M15.  This is how you can track that down: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248820/find-all-references-to-a-cell/28418485#28418485

Answer (score 0):

About the circular reference, I have two questions:

1. Does the value of L15 depends directly on the value of M15 (i.e., L = IF( M15 = "Y", do this, no that)?
2. Does the value of L15 depends indirectly on the value of M15 (i.e., L = N+P, but N = IF( M15 = "Y", do this, no that)?

If none of the questions are yes, it should never give you a circular reference at all. If it happens, means there is a dependency.

Now, about giving the opposite result, I can see in your formula:
`=IF(L15=0;"N";"Y")`, so:  if L15 is equal to 0, M will get the value of "N".

Remember: `=IF(condition;value if true; else).

You can chose between two conditions:

- L15 equal to  0, then: `M15 = IF(L15=0;"Y";"N")`.
- L15 different than 0, then: `M15 = IF(L15<>0;"Y";"N")`.